# Setting a default thumbnail url if no thumbnail

Tags: php, thumbnails

I have created a code to get an existing post's thumbnail and echo the url, but I would like to be able to have it get a default url is the post doesn't have a set thumbnail.

Any help would be appreciated! Here's my code so far

```
    <?php
$thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
$thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id,'thumbnail', false);
?>

<div class="content" style="background-image:url(<?php echo $thumb_url[0]; ?>);">

Default Thumbnail url : http://www.website.com/img/default.jpg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set up a condition to check that thumb_id isn't empty. If it is, use your alternative image. Pretty simple stuff.

```
    <?php
$thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();

if ( $thumb_id ) {
$thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id,'thumbnail', false);
$thumb_url = $thumb_url[0];
} else {
$thumb_url = 'http://www.website.com/img/default.jpg';
}
?>

<div class="content" style="background-image:url(<?php echo $thumb_url; ?>);">
```

Comment: It's what I thought, but while it works if there's a thumb, it doesn't echo the url if there isn't

Comment: Oops - I've edited my answer.